# What should the dos/don'ts contain?

Tags: discussion

Currently the about page (https://joomla.stackexchange.com/about) includes the following:

Ask about...

- Specific programming problems
- Software algorithms
- Coding techniques
- Software development tools

Don't ask about...

- Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)
- Product or service recommendations or comparisons
- Requests for lists of things, polls, opinions, discussions, etc.
- Anything not directly related to writing computer programs

Essentially, what kind of Questions do we want here? Is there something that needs to be added? Something that should be removed?

Answer (score 6):

We could change that to:

Ask about...

- Specific Joomla Framework problems
- Joomla CMS installation, usage and customisation issues
- Questions about Joomla extensions

Don't ask about...

- Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)
- Product or service recommendations or comparisons
- Requests for lists of things, polls, opinions, discussions, etc.
- Anything not directly related to Joomla

I've included three DO's I think we should have.

The only DONT that I think needs changing is the last one, since we need to accommodate non-programmers on the CMS side. Also, are plugins and extensions in scope for this?

I'm just taking a shot at this, other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I would change do #2 to something like "Joomla CMS installation, usage and customisation issues". On do #3, you don't need to say "plugin", because it is an extension.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated them

Answer (score 3):

We'll need to include something about promoting commercial extensions and denigrating one extension over another unless specific features are mentioned.  Regarding the sh404 question : "use this it's free and better!" is not adequate but "The extension I use fixes the canonical url problem" is valid.

Answer (score 3):

I think there might be some dispute about asking about Joomla Extensions. I've seen so many people asking how to do this with that extension (even with commercial extensions), however I always say to the user that they should contact the developer as it should be the done thing. Having said that, I know some developers:

1. Charge for support.
2. Don't provide support.
3. Take a long time to reply or sometimes not at all.

So I think **Questions about Joomla extensions** should be discussed a little further.