# Help Section: What topics can I ask about here?

Tags: discussion

We are getting many questions that are not in the scope of this website.

For example: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/17009/advice-on-setting-up-joomla-for-client-management-and-subscriptions - this question is definitely out of the scope here, and can't be answered.

When I want to comment on such questions and explain why their question will be closed, I want to link to the appropriate help section - at the section of **[What topics can I ask about here?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**.

However, the problem is that this section says nothing about the topics and the scope of the questions that are acceptable here.

**I checked a couple of other SE websites to see how they are doing it:**
 - WP site: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
 - SuperUser : https://superuser.com/help/on-topic

**So my questions here:**

- Is our Topics section that empty, because we are in beta?
- Shouldn't we take care this section, so new users get introduced into the scope of the website and how to edit this section?
- And most important, we shall start the discussion to define the type of questions/topics this site is accepting.

*There was a similar discussion some time ago here: [What should the dos/don'ts contain?](https://joomla.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-should-the-dos-donts-contain)
Not sure what was the outcome of that discussion.

Answer (score 2):

I believe **yes**, it is pretty much empty as we're in Beta.

For the time being, perhaps rather than link to the Help Section stating what type of question should be asked, it may be an idea to link to OP to the section that states what type of questions should be avoided:

https://joomla.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask